# How to add a title to a PHP email?

Tags: php, email

When sending an email with php, how can I change the title of an email that gets sent, such as in the picture below.

[image: Google Email List]

I want to change the word "contact" to something else.
Here is my current code:

```
$msg = "Thank you, " ."$inputUsername". ", for joining "."<a href='http://www.gamingpopulace.com'>Gaming Populace!</a> "."We hope that you enjoy the site and become very active." ;
          $topic = "Thanks for joining";
          $headers = "From: contact@gamingpopulace.com";
          $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: contact@gamingpopulace.com\r\n";
          $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";
          $email = preg_replace("([\r\n])", "", $email);
          if (mail($email,$topic,$msg, $headers)) {
                header('Location: ../index ');
          }else {
                header('Location: ../index ');
              }
```

Do I need to add another header?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$headers  = "From: Gaming Populace < contact@gamingpopulace.com >\n";
```

Modify your header like this